# Can't add an object from scene to a Visual Scripting node in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object, bolt

I can't add an object from scene to a Visual Scripting node in Unity. While I am dragging a object from a samplescene section to a scipt graph on a GameObject node it shows an unavailable symbol and I just can't add an object to a Game Object node. The same with the list of game objects. So, how can I add an object to a GameObject node?
Sorry for so stupid question, I am a real beginner

I tried to add an object to a GameObject node but it didn't work.